# Java math sequence (Beginner)

Tags: java, math

```
System.out.print(3+2+1-5+4%2-1/4+6);
```

Output: `7`

How does the sequence of performing math operators work? Does Java follow the algebraic PEMDAS or something else?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html For learning operator precedence

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Java follows the standard arithmetic order of operations.

However, you may be expecting a different answer than what you got. This is because the value `1/4` is evaluated using *integer* arithmetic, because both the `1` and the `4` are integers. The result of `1/4` in integer arithmetic is 0.

To ask the compiler to evaluate this using floating point, use something like `1.0/4.0`. After doing that, you should get the floating point result 6.75 (which is probably what you expected).

Comment: Correct. This is how it will get executed (3+2+1-5+(4%2)-(1/4)+6). As explained, 1/4 will be evaluated to 0 as at least one of them should be a floating point number. Additionally, if you are storing the value in a variable, the variable should also be float or double, else you will loose anything after the decimal place. Something like, (float x = (3+2+1-5+(4%2)-(1.0f/4)+6))

Answer (score 3):

Java will follow an order of precedence(order of operations)

1. `()`
2. `*`, `/`, `%`
3. `+`, `-`

That is all you'll need for this problem but there is more [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Java will follow the same order of operations. The only change is the %, which follow the same order as multiplication and division.